# Issue in installing BI feature for VS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, business-intelligence

I one issue in installing Business intilligence for visual studio 2008. When I install this BI tool, BI feature gets added to visual studio 2010 and not to the visual studio 2008. I want this feature in VS 2008. Setup file is for sql server 2008 R2.

Does anyone has the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall BI tools
2. Uninstall visual studio 2010
3. Install BI tools
4. Install visual studio 2010

Good luck

Comment: Do u have any reference for this about why is this happening

Comment: did you check your intalation log?

Comment: no. when is this generated... can u let me know how this log is accessed

Comment: This [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx) will help with logs